# Why Google Drive getExportLinks returns null?

Tags: java, ms-word

I'm uploading a Word document:

```
    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
    body.setTitle(file.getName());
    body.setMimeType(mimeType);

    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, file);

    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File uploadedFile = service.files()
            .insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

    String downloadUrl = file.getExportLinks().get(mimeType);
```

The upload goes through fine. However, call to file.getExportLinks() returns null, and, thus, this line a null pointer. Does anybody know why getExportLinks() returns null?

Answer (score 1):

Grab the document key and create the link like this:

```
Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
File file = driveService.files().get(this.spreadsheetKey).execute();
String downloadUrl = file.getExportLinks().get("application/pdf");
```

Example downloadUrl:
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=**somekey**&exportFormat=pdf

Note: you can paste the above url into a browser, and it will download as long as you are logged into google drive.

No idea if you can create the link without the document key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct `Scope` to access the links.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes

Comment: i have set scope to "drive" and the export links are still empty. https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive.html